# Como armazenar a data e hora a cada click no formulário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário e preciso armazenar a data e hora a cada click do formulário ou ao menos no primeiro.
Acho que isso deve ser feito via JQuery ou JavaScript.
A cada pergunta, o formulário faz tem um button com type="button" e o ultimo botão faz o submit.
A ideia é pegar o incio e o fim do preenchimento do formulário e/ou quanto tempo leva entre uma questão e outra.

Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54227/discussion-on-question-by-fabricio-wm-como-armazenar-a-data-e-hora-a-cada-click)

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, você possui um formulário divido em várias etapas. E existe um botão responsavel por realizar a transição das etapas. Supondo que haja um botão para cada etapa do formulario, você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

html

```
<form>
    <div class="etapa">
        ...
        <button type="button" name="etapa1">Avançar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="etapa">
        ...
        <button type="button" name="etapa2">Avançar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="etapa">
        ...
        <button type="button" name="etapa3">Avançar</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

javascript

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("div.etapa button").click(function(){

        var dados = {};
            dados.etapa = jQuery(this).attr('name');

        jQuery.ajax({
            url  : 'logEtapas.php',
            data : dados,
            type : 'post'
        });

    });

});
```

php

```
if ( $_POST ){

    $etapa    = $_POST["etapa"];
    $datahora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    //Executar inserção dos dados no banco

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela força, @Thiago.
Você entendeu bem, mas esse php vai ficar no arquivo que vai receber o Post? Se sim, como que eu vou obter a data e hora no momento do click se isso será feito depois?
Desculpa, mas eu não entendi bem a colocação do jquery e do php.
Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade, toda vez que os botões de 'Avançar' receberem o click, sera realizada a requisição para a página `logEtapas.php` (por exemplo) que fará apenas a inserção da data/hora do click e o name do `button` (apenas para identificar as passagens). Na última etapa deverá existir um `button type="submit"` que enviará os dados para a página responsável por fazer a inserção dos dados do formulário no banco. Outra opção seria a cada salvar as informações sempre que avançar as etapas. só que ai teria que alterar os scripts acima.

Comment: Tem um problema @Thiago.
Dessa forma que você está falando, vai armazenar informações a cada vez que o usuário clicar em avançar e eu vou ter que alterar a estrutura da minha tabela.
Eu criei uma coluna chamada time_click para a cada click vai avançando e no final, deverá pegar o post de cada pergunta e o tempo de cada click.

Comment: Posta o script da sua tabela pra eu entender melhor?

Comment: `'CREATE TABLE giga.pv_resposta(
seq int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cod_formulario int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
cod_pergunta int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
resposta varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
cod_seq_questionario int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
time_click varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(seq),
KEY FK_Formulario_Padrao (cod_formulario,cod_pergunta) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Formulario_Padrao FOREIGN KEY (cod_formulario, cod_pergunta) REFERENCES pv_formulario_padrao (cod_formulario, cod_pergunta)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=199 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;`'

Comment: A inserção é feita por Stored Procedure.
Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a forma mais correta, mas eu faria da seguinte maneira:

html

```
<form>
    <div class="etapa">
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_pergunta" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_seq_questionario" value="1" />
        Pergunta nro 1
        <select name="resposta">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Avançar</div>
    </div>
</form>

<form>
    <div class="etapa">
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_pergunta" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_seq_questionario" value="2" />
        Pergunta nro 2
        <select name="resposta">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Avançar</div>
    </div>
</form>

<form>
    <div class="etapa">
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_pergunta" value="3" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_seq_questionario" value="3" />
        Pergunta nro 3
        <select name="resposta">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Avançar</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

javascript

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("form").submit(function(){

        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url  : 'salvar_respostas.php',
            data : dados,
            type : 'post'
        });

    });

});
```

php

```
if ( $_POST ){

    $agora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO pv_resposta (cod_formulario, cod_pergunta, resposta, cod_seq_questionario, time_click) VALUES ('3', '" . $_POST['cod_pergunta'] . "', '" . $_POST['resposta'] . "', '" . $_POST['cod_seq_questionario'] . "', '" . agora . "');"

    //Executar inserção dos dados no banco

}
```

Comment: Faz sentido, @thiago.
Vou testar e conforme for, eu marco como ok.
Obrigado.